# Why is ANTLR omitting the final token *and* not producing an error?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have a grammar like this (anything which looks convoluted is a result of it being a subset of the actual grammar which contains more red herrings):

```
grammar Query;

startExpression
  : WS? expression WS? EOF
  ;

expression
  | maybeDefaultBooleanExpression
  ;

maybeDefaultBooleanExpression
  : defaultBooleanExpression
  | queryFragment
  ;

defaultBooleanExpression
  : nested += queryFragment (WS nested += queryFragment)+
  ;

queryFragment
  : unquotedQuery
  | quotedQuery
  ;

unquotedQuery
  : UNQUOTED
  ;

quotedQuery
  : QUOTED
  ;

UNQUOTED
  : UnquotedStartChar
    UnquotedChar*
  ;

fragment
UnquotedStartChar
  : EscapeSequence
  | ~( ' ' | '\r' | '\t' | '\u000C' | '\n' | '\\' | ':'
     | '"' | '\u201C' | '\u201D'    // DoubleQuote
     | '\'' | '\u2018' | '\u2019'   // SingleQuote
     | '(' | ')' | '[' | ']' | '{' | '}' | '~'
     | '&' | '|' | '!' | '^' | '?' | '*' | '/' | '+' | '-' | '$' )
  ;

fragment
UnquotedChar
  : EscapeSequence
  | ~( ' ' | '\r' | '\t' | '\u000C' | '\n' | '\\' | ':'
     | '"' | '\u201C' | '\u201D'    // DoubleQuote
     | '\'' | '\u2018' | '\u2019'   // SingleQuote
     | '(' | ')' | '[' | ']' | '{' | '}' | '~'
     | '&' | '|' | '!' | '^' | '?' | '*' )
  ;

QUOTED
  : '"'
    QuotedChar*
    '"'
  ;

fragment
QuotedChar
  : ~( '\\'
     |  | '\u201C' | '\u201D'      // DoubleQuote
     | '\r' | '\n' | '?' | '*' )
  ;


WS : ( ' ' | '\r' | '\t' | '\u000C' | '\n' )+;
```

If I call the lexer myself directly:

```
    CharStream input = CharStreams.fromString("A \"");
    QueryLexer lexer = new QueryLexer(input);
    lexer.removeErrorListeners();
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    System.out.println(tokens.LT(0));
    System.out.println(tokens.LT(1));
    System.out.println(tokens.LT(2));
    System.out.println(tokens.LT(3));
```

I get:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4

    at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:385)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:462)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.CodePointCharStream$CodePoint8BitCharStream.getText(CodePointCharStream.java:160)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer.notifyListeners(Lexer.java:360)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer.nextToken(Lexer.java:144)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.fetch(BufferedTokenStream.java:169)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.sync(BufferedTokenStream.java:152)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream.LT(CommonTokenStream.java:100)
```

This makes some kind of sense, though I think a proper ANTLR exception might have been better.

What I really don't get, though, is that when I feed this through the complete *parser*:

```
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(tokens);
        parser.removeErrorListeners();
        parser.addErrorListener(LoggingErrorListener.get());
        parser.setErrorHandler(new BailErrorStrategy());

        // Performance hack as per the ANTLR v4 FAQ
        parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.SLL);
        ParseTree expression;
        try
        {
            expression = parser.startExpression();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // It catches a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException here.

            parser.reset();
            parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.LL);
            expression = parser.startExpression();
        }
```

I get:

```
tokens = {org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream@1811} 
 channel = 0
 tokenSource = {MyQueryLexer@1810} 
 tokens = {java.util.ArrayList@1816}  size = 3
  0 = {org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonToken@1818} "[@0,0:0='A',<13>,1:0]"
  1 = {org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonToken@1819} "[@1,1:1=' ',<32>,1:1]"
  2 = {org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonToken@1820} "[@2,3:2='<EOF>',<-1>,1:3]"
 p = 2
 fetchedEOF = true

expression = {MyQueryParser$StartExpressionContext@1813} "[]"
 children = {java.util.ArrayList@1827}  size = 3
  0 = {MyQueryParser$ExpressionContext@1831} "[87]"
  1 = {org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.TerminalNodeImpl@1832} " "
  2 = {org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.TerminalNodeImpl@1833} "<EOF>"
```

Here I would have expected to get a `RecognitionException`, but somehow the parsing succeeds, and is missing the invalid bit of the token data at the end.

Questions are:

(1) Is this by design?

(2) If so, how can I detect this and have it treated as a syntax error?

**Further investigation**

When I went looking for the culprit for who was catching the `StringIndexOutOfBoudsException` and eating it, it turns out that it comes all the way out to our catch block. So I guess ANTLR never got a chance to finish building that last invalid token..?

I'm not entirely sure what's supposed to happen, but I guess I expected that ANTLR would have caught it, created an invalid token and continued.

I then drilled further in and found that Token#nextToken() was throwing an exception, and the docs made it seem like that wasn't supposed to happen, so I ended up filing a ticket about that.

Answer (score 3):

Until very recent builds, ANTLR4's adaptive mechanism has the "feature" of being able to recover from single-token-missing and single-extra-token parses if there were only one viable alternative in that part of the token stream.  Now recently, [apparently that behavior has changed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768855/why-did-upgrading-from-antlr-4-5-3-to-antlr-4-7-change-the-single-token-deletion) So if you're using an older build as I am, you'll still see the adaptive parsing.  Maybe Parr and Harwill will fix that.

**Like you, I recognized the need for a perfect input stream and zero parse errors, "overlooked" or not.  To create a "strict parser" follow these steps:**

1. Make a class called perhaps "StrictErrorStrategy that inherit from/extend DefaultErrorStrategy.  You need to override the Recover, RecoverInline, and Sync methods.  Bottom line here is we throw exceptions for anything that goes wrongs, and make no attempt to re-sync the code after an extra/missing token.  Here's my C# code, your java will look very similar:

   ```
   public class StrictErrorStrategy : DefaultErrorStrategy
   {
       public override void Recover(Parser recognizer, RecognitionException e)
       {
       IToken token = recognizer.CurrentToken;
       string message = string.Format("parse error at line {0}, position {1} right before {2} ", token.Line, token.Column, GetTokenErrorDisplay(token));
       throw new Exception(message, e);
       }

   public override IToken RecoverInline(Parser recognizer)
   {
       IToken token = recognizer.CurrentToken;
       string message = string.Format("parse error at line {0}, position {1} right before {2} ", token.Line, token.Column, GetTokenErrorDisplay(token));
       throw new Exception(message, new InputMismatchException(recognizer));
   }

   public override void Sync(Parser recognizer) { /* do nothing to resync */}
   }
   ```
2. Make a new lexer that implements a single method:

   ```
   public class StrictLexer : <YourGeneratedLexerNameHere>
   {
      public override void Recover(LexerNoViableAltException e)
       {
           string message = string.Format("lex error after token {0} at position {1}", _lasttoken.Text, e.StartIndex);
           throw new ParseCanceledException(BasicEnvironment.SyntaxError);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use your lexer and strategy:

   ```
     AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(stream);
     StrictLexer lexer = new BailLexer(inputStream);
     CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
     LISBASICParser parser = new LISBASICParser(tokenStream);
     parser.RemoveErrorListeners();
     parser.ErrorHandler = new StrictErrorStrategy();
   ```

This works great, actual code from one of my projects that has a "zero-tolerance rule" about syntax errors.  I got the code and ideas from Terence Parr's great book on ANTLR4.

Comment: I'm using the latest release, but this approach still seems like it should work.

Comment: So... At the moment, we're using BailErrorStrategy, which seems like it will always throw an exception anyway. This might mean that the only thing we want to do is override the lexer to prevent recovering.

Comment: Nope... apparently it's no good. I have a breakpoint on the error strategy, and although `sync` is being called, `recover` and `recoverInline` are not being called at all, so nothing I do in those methods can help. Nothing ever calls the overridden `recover` method in `StrictQueryLexer` either, so that also can't help. I also tried overriding the other `recover` method too, and that isn't being called either.

Comment: I ended up filing [a ticket](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1948) because I couldn't figure out the correct behaviour from their own method docs...